# Use YAML templates from multiple repositories

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I currently have the following files:

`azure-pipelines.yml` in repository A:

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: git
      name: {MyAzureDevOpsRepoB}

stages:
- template: sharedTemplateInRepoB.yml@templates
```

The file `sharedTemplateInRepoB.yml` in repository B, is something like this:

```
stages:
- stage: XXX
  jobs:
  - template: someTemplateInRepoA.yml
```

The issue is that the file in repository B references a template that is currently living inside repository A, where the actual `azure-pipelines.yml` file lives.

When I start the pipeline, I get an error message that says that file `someTemplateInRepoA.yml` could not be found in repository B. However, I know for sure that the file exists in repo A.

Is this a supported scenario? Is there a workaround eventually to achieve my goal?

Comment: Since `someTemplateInRepoA.yml` is in `repositoryA`, why you reference it in `sharedTemplateInRepoB.yml` in `repository B`? why don't you use it in `azure-pipelines.yml` in `repositoryA`?

Answer (score 2):

In order to use templates from repo A in repo B you also have to add:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: templatesFromRepoA
    type: git
    name: {MyAzureDevOpsRepoA}
stages:
- stage: XXX
  jobs:
  - template: someTemplateInRepoA.yml@templatesFromRepoA
```